# Can't install ui package

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I've just downloaded the laravel 6 and I'm trying to install composer require laravel/ui package, but I'm getting the following composer error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're using Laravel 6 and the package you're trying to require wants Laravel 7.

If you change the composer require line to this:

```
composer require laravel/ui:^1.0 --dev
```

It should download the correct package you need.

Edit: If you see this error in the future, the best thing you can do is go to the repository of said package (in this case [this repo](https://github.com/laravel/ui)) and open the [composer.json](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/2.x/composer.json) of said repo and see what the requirements for the package are. In this case I linked the composer.json of the most recent release, which states it needs Laravel 7.

Answer (score -1):

This will help you . Try This :

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Comment: That's exactly what he tried and gave him the error he posted.